# How do I get parameter value from a GParam object

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

**What:**
Gtk+ 3 with PyGObject bindings and Python 2.7.

**Question:**
How can I get the value of a `GParamObject`? I assume it has a value, (otherwise what would be the point of it?) but I have spent several hours googling and experimenting and have not been able find the answer to this seemingly simple question. Maybe my assumption that is has a value is unfounded.

**Background:** I have a Gtk.Stack, and I have connected a callback to the `"notify::visible-child"` signals that does some stuff when the `visible-child` changes. Something like this

```
stack.connect("notify::visible-child", on_stack_changed)

def on_stack_changed(stack, param):
    print "stack's visible child changed"
    print param  # Prints: <GParamObject 'visible-child'>
```

Now, since the [GTK.Stack docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Stack.html#Gtk.Stack.props.visible_child) indicate that the `visible_child` property's value is the visible child widget, I expect to be able to get a reference to the widget from the param passed to my callback. But I have not been able to figure out how to get any value from the GParam object.

I have tried every variation of things like `param.value`, `param.get_value()` etc. that I could think of, but to no avail.

Of course, since the stack object is also passed to my callback, I could always do `stack. get_visible_child()`, but that is no fun, is it? :D

So, any explanation of the `GParamObject`, its intended use, or links to examples of its use would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Here is a standalone example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def on_stack_changed(stack, param):
    for attr in dir(param):
        print "{}: {}".format(attr, getattr(param, attr))

stack = Gtk.Stack()
stack.add_titled(Gtk.Label('Child 1'), 'child1', 'Child 1')
stack.add_titled(Gtk.Label('Child 2'), 'child2', 'Child 2')
stack.connect("notify::visible-child", on_stack_changed)

stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher(stack=stack)

header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar(custom_title=stack_switcher, show_close_button=True)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(500, 250)
window.set_titlebar(header_bar)
window.add(stack)

window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

As suggested by [liberforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569224/how-do-i-get-parameter-value-from-a-gparam-object/46570103?noredirect=1#comment80114880_46570103), I tried `print dir(param)` which results in this output:

```
__doc__: The widget currently visible in the stack
__gtype__: <GType GParamObject (94151103218704)>
blurb: The widget currently visible in the stack
flags: 1073742051
name: visible-child
nick: Visible child
owner_type: <GType GtkStack (94151105445744)>
value_type: <GType GtkWidget (94151104851072)>
```

This helps a great deal in understanding what information is available from the `GParamObject`. As expected the `value_type` is a `GtkWidget`, but I still don't see how to get the value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because it doesn't exist there. What you get in `param` seems to be a `GParamSpec` which is just metadata about a parameter, holding its name, type, flags... I can't find a reference on `GParamObject` in the PyGObject documentation. But If I look the C documentation of the `notify` signal, indeed, thats a `GParamSpec` that is passed there, so that may be a [`GObject.ParamSpecObject`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GObject-2.0/classes/ParamSpec.html#GObject.ParamSpec)

So I think your `get_visible_child` is the way to go. You may get the same result in a more flexible way using using the `GParamSpec` with `stack.get_property(param.name)`.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the standalone example modified:
In the callback, I use 3 different ways of getting the visible child, all working. They all return the same object instance, as confirmed by `id`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def on_stack_changed(stack, param):
    print 'stack.get_visible_child():      {}'.format(id(stack.get_visible_child()))
    print 'stack.get_property(param.name): {}'.format(id(stack.get_property(param.name)))
    print 'stack.props.visible_child:      {}'.format(id(stack.props.visible_child))

stack = Gtk.Stack()
stack.add_titled(Gtk.Label('Child 1'), 'child1', 'Child 1')
stack.add_titled(Gtk.Label('Child 2'), 'child2', 'Child 2')
stack.connect("notify::visible-child", on_stack_changed)

stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher(stack=stack)

header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar(custom_title=stack_switcher, show_close_button=True)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(500, 250)
window.set_titlebar(header_bar)
window.add(stack)

window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Using `print vars(param)` may help you see what is really in your object.

Comment: GParamSpec does not seem to be a `GObject.ParamSpecObject` as `param.get_name()` throws an `AttributeError`. Likewise `print vars(param)` throws `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`  

 I think you are right that the `GParamSpec` is just metadata.

Comment: Interesting. If you update your code sample to have a standalone example, maybe I could sort it out. It's strange to have an object and not really know what it is... BTW, if `print vars(param)` doesn't work, try `print dir(param)`.

Comment: I added a standalone example, and `print dir(param)` was a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: I just saw you did a mistake. It's not `param.get_name()` you're supposed to use, it's `param.name`

Comment: I have added an updated version of your standalone example which show the different ways to do what get the visible child.

Comment: Thank you, that works. But my question was really about the `GParamObject` and why it does not seem to have an attribute for the parameter value itself, while it seems to have all the other information about the parameter (`value-type`, `name`, `owner-type` etc.). I think your first answer was best, that the `GParamObject` seems to be just metadata about the parameter, and so does not have the value.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's only metadata. Please read the documentation of `GParamSpec` and `GValue` for implementation details.